# Cannot get paypal "VERIFIED" or "INVALID" on IPN

Tags: javascript, meteor, paypal

I am trying to implement a paypal payment system through their API. Do not ask why I don't use braintree or stripe... it's a client specification for some reasons that it goes through plain paypal and now I am struggling to implement the payment verification.

I implemented the paypal payment form with the sandbox that works. I mentioned a notify-url to get feedback and it is then that I have to do the paypal verification (to make sure the payment information I received is real) according to this documentation : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/ and this https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#id08CKFJ00JYK

My code is as follow :

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

import moment from 'moment';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http'

Picker.middleware(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : false }));
// Picker.middleware(bodyParser.json());


let postRoutes = Picker.filter(function(req, res) {
    return req.method === "POST"
});

postRoutes.route('/payment_received', function(params, request, response, next){
    response.statusCode = 200;
    response.end();

  let convertAsyncToSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(HTTP.call);
    let test = JSON.stringify(request.body);

    let body2 = 'cmd=_notify-validate&' + test.slice(1, -1).replace(/"/g,'').replace(/:/g,"=").replace(/,/g,'&')
    console.log('-------body2-----------')
    console.log(body2)
  let result2 = convertAsyncToSync('POST', "https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", {
    headers: {
        'Connection': 'close'
    },
    body: body2
  });

    console.log('----------------result2------------')
    console.log(result2);
  console.log('----------------result2.BODY------------')
    console.log(result2.body);

})
```

According to the doc I though I should get a "VERIFIED" or "INVALID" response, instead of this I get a full HTML page which I have no idea why.

Even if I test the post request with a simple REST client I do not get the good reply. No idea why and I am stuck there. Anyone with paypal experience ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this package it works for me like a breeze.
 https://github.com/mbreuer23/meteor-ipn-listener/